# Symfony 4, include assets from vendor directory

Tags: php, symfony, twig, composer-php, bootstrap-4

I would like to load vendor assets, downloaded with composer inside vendor directory, from my twig template.

Using a relative path is one solution (in this example I'm going to include bootstrap css, but the same problem is for any other libs required from composer, as jQuery, jQueryUI  etc. )

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset('../vendor/twbs/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css') }}" >
```

Symfony docs suggest to use asset:install in order to generate a symlink from vendor directory to public, but I was unable to understand how it works.
assets:install -h wasn't so clear to let me understand how to link a specific vendor path to the public directory.

Creating a simlink with

```
ln -s /path/of/vendor/lib /path/public/dir
```

works fine but, symlinks created will be deleted every time I look for an update with composer.

Any idea about "a best practice" to include assets from vendor directory?

Thank you

Comment: did you have any problem with `assets:install` as that is the best practice, and just running that command will get all assets into your public dir

Comment: you run it in your project root directory as `bin/console assets:install`

Comment: sorry, could you explain to me how it works? That's the command
    console assets:install public --symlink
I've used it inside the vendor directory of bootstrap (dists sub directory) That's the output: 

    Trying to install assets as absolute symbolic links. 

    [OK] No assets were provided by any bundle.

Comment: I run it from netbeans, from console. Im able to execute che command, the problem is that I'm not able to understand how to explain 
"please, LINK the vendor/twbs/bootstrap/css ---> public directory"

running the command, as I wrote, reports this output:


    Trying to install assets as absolute symbolic links.

                                                                                
 [OK] No assets were provided by any bundle.

Comment: I think, noone is able to provide a correct answer to this question.
Because @kunicmarko20 wrote just what the official docs of symfony reports about assets install, and I didn't asked for a copy/paste of the official documentation.

Anyway webencore pack could be a good solution, instead of load assets via composer.
https://symfony.com/doc/current/frontend/encore/bootstrap.html

I'd still like to understand what is the "best way" to do that, instead of use something that "just works"...

Comment: Do you have found a solution? I have same problem

Comment: @Code-Source the best way is to install webpack encore as reported inside the official docs 
[link](https://symfony.com/doc/current/frontend.html) 

I'd like to configure framework.yml as it was for "assetic" (old package used in symfony 2.x).
For assetic it was necessary to configure source path (the vendor path) and the destination path (the public directory) inside a config.yml

With asset, the config file is framework.yml but assets: tag 
doesn't works as for assetic (and I'd still like to understand the best way to do that).

Comment: Code-Source that's the link to the guide of assets
[link](https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/configuration/framework.html#assets)

what @kunicmarko20 wrote was useless, while it was just explained inside the basic docs of symfony.
[link](https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/asset.html)

Answer (score 1):

In terms of 'Best Practice', I generally use [npm](https://www.npmjs.com) with [gulp](https://gulpjs.com) or something to that effect, which generates distribution css and js files that are output to a designated file in `public/`.

Here's an example from a recent project `package.json` file

```
{
  "devDependencies": {
    "bootstrap": "^4.1.3",
    "gulp": "^4.0.0",
    "gulp-concat": "^2.6.1",
    "gulp-sass": "^3.1.0"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "compile:styles": "gulp styles"
  }
}
```

Rather run `npm install --save-dev bootstrap gulp gulp-concat gulp-sass` to get the latest versions etc.

And you'll need this `gulpfile.js` too

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var concat = require('gulp-concat');
var sass = require('gulp-sass');

gulp.task('styles', function(){
    return gulp
        .src([
            'app/Resources/sass/main.scss',
            ])
        .pipe(sass({outputStyle:'compressed', includePaths: ['node_modules']}).on('error', sass.logError))
        .pipe(concat('styles.min.css'))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('public/css'));
    });
```

Once setup, you can run `npm run compile:styles` from the console and the `app/Resources/sass/main.scss` SASS file will be pre-processed, minified and output to `public/css/styles.min.css`.

Note that the gulp file includes the node_modules folder so you can import bootstrap inside the `main.scss` file, e.g.

```
$primary: #55a367;

@import 'bootstrap/scss/bootstrap';
```

From a twig template:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{{ asset('css/styles.min.css') }}">
```

I generally commit both the `main.scss` and `styles.min.css`

Answer (score 1):

The reason why you can't tell the `assets:install` to link and arbitrary vendor directory is that the command is designed to loop through the list of installed bundles and link a well-known directory (`Resources/public`) directory if it exists. It relies on both the short bundle name and the directory existing, so it can only work with symfony bundles, there's no support for other libraries like bootstrap or jquery. (Link to current [command source](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/c417fd700a3a16ca09bcc73989e9b397c456d141/src/Symfony/Bundle/FrameworkBundle/Command/AssetsInstallCommand.php#L135)).

The recommended way to handle frontend libraries nowadays is [encore](https://symfony.com/doc/current/frontend.html).

In a situation where that's not possible, you could use [composer scripts](https://getcomposer.org/doc/articles/scripts.md#what-is-a-script-). I wouldn't call this "best practice", might end up being more trouble than it's worth but is an option you can consider.

You would create a shell, php script or console command where you basically replicate the functionality of `assets:install` to link your library assets. You will still need to manually update the script when you install a new library, but you can configure it to automatically run after installing or updating packages.

Copy this simple sample bash script into you project directory, name it `install_vendors.sh`:

```
#!/bin/bash

BASE_PATH=`pwd`
PUBLIC="public"

if [ "$1" != "" ]; then
    PUBLIC=$1
fi;

PUBLIC=${BASE_PATH}/${PUBLIC}/vendor
VENDOR=${BASE_PATH}/vendor

rm $PUBLIC -rf
mkdir $PUBLIC

function link_asset
{
    SOURCE_DIR=${VENDOR}/$1
    TARGET_DIR=${PUBLIC}/$2
    ln -s $SOURCE_DIR $TARGET_DIR
}

link_asset twbs/bootstrap/dist bootstrap
```

Add it to the `scripts` section of `composer.json` and the `auto-scripts`:

```
"scripts": {
    "vendors:install": "bash install_vendors.sh",
    "auto-scripts": {
        "cache:clear": "symfony-cmd",
        "assets:install %PUBLIC_DIR%": "symfony-cmd"
        "@vendors:install"
    },
    // ...
}
```

You can also execute it at any time with `composer run vendors:install`.

Then include them in your twig files: `{{ asset('vendor/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css') }}`.